# Populating additional select input after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a select input.  When changed, the following is triggered

```
$('#type').change(function() {
    var selectedYear = $("#year option:selected").val();
    var selectedProduct = $("#product option:selected").val();
    var selectedType = $("#type option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "./report",
        data: { 
            year : selectedYear,
            product : selectedProduct,
            type : selectedType
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        var url = $('meta[name="base_url"]').attr('content');

        $('#displayImage').attr('src', '');
        $('#displayImage').attr('src', url + data);
        $('#displayImage').css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

The url it calls triggers a function that essentially fillws up an array with image paths.  Once the image array is populated, I do

```
if(!empty($imageArray)) {
     return $imageArray;
}
```

Now in the done section in my ajax call I display the image.  This works fine if the array only has one image path.  However, if there is more than one image path in the array, I need to display an additional select input so they can select the appropiate image.

How could something like this be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to have an empty < select > ready to be unhidden. Once you have the data you could populate the select like this-

```
$.each($imageArray, function(key, value) {   
 $('#myEmptyAndNowUnhiddenSelect')
     .append($("<option></option>")
     .attr("value",key)
     .text(value)); 
});
```